How to set encoding for HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in jetty12? to achieve it?
In jetty9, I can set the encoding for request, response and uri by inheriting handlerWrapper and rewriting handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request,
HttpServletResponse response). Is there an alternative method in jetty12?
I set it up like this
`
protected void doFilterCharacterEncoding(
HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(URICharset)) {
        request.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.queryEncoding", URICharset);
    }

    if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(requestCharacterEncoding) && request.getCharacterEncoding() == null) {
        request.setCharacterEncoding(requestCharacterEncoding);
    }
    if (StringUtil.isNotBlank(responseCharacterEncoding)) {
        response.setCharacterEncoding(responseCharacterEncoding);
    }
}

`
Is there any alternative method?

For Jetty 12, the HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse only exist in the Environment that supports those objects. (as of today that would be the environment with the IDs ee10, ee9, and ee8)
The .setCharacterEncoding(String) methods on both of those classes only apply to Servlet behaviors.
Your code is either incomplete, or you are not showing how you get the charset from the HTTP request headers or the HTTP response headers. (You should honor the charset from the HTTP request/response headers, only force the header for the cases where the headers are unclear/vague/ambiguous/empty/unset)
HttpServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(String)
The charset of the request has an impact on the HttpServletRequest.getReader() API call.
The charset of the request comes from the following lookup.

If the HttpServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(String) has set a charset use it.
If the HTTP request header Content-Type has a charset attribute, use it.
If the HTTP request header Content-Type has a mime-type that is registered with a charset, use that registered charset.
If the HTTP request header Locale exists, use the default charset for that locale.
If ServletContext.setRequestCharacterEncoding(String) was called, use that value.
Default to ISO8859-1 per HTTP spec.

This does not impact other APIs or behaviors (like request form parsing)
HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(String)
The charset of the response has an impact on the HttpServletResponse.getWriter() API call.
The charset of the response comes from the following lookup.

If the HttpServletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(String) has set a charset use it.
If the HTTP response header Content-Type has a charset attribute, use it.
If the HTTP response header Content-Type has a mime-type that is registered with a charset, use that registered charset.
If the HTTP response header Locale is set, use the default charset for that locale.
If the ServletContext.setResponseCharacterEncoding(String) was called, use that value.
Default to ISO8859-1 per HTTP spec.

Jetty Core
From a Jetty Core Handler, you cannot influence this behavior in the Servlet layer by setting a value for charset like you are attempting to do.  That's because on Jetty Core, there's no concept of charset being separate from the Content-Type, they are tied together, like the HTTP spec intends.
Instead, you have to think of this as adjusting the Content-Type header to fit the needs of both your application AND the rules of the mime-type you are attempting to adjust (eg: you cannot set a charset header on application/json as the spec for that mime-type rejects any attempt at setting a charset attribute. These rules are but that's handled by Jetty's MimeTypes object)
Jetty Core is not a great place to attempt to influence Servlet behavior.
Options
I can see two choices for you.

Update the ServletContext for default request and response charset via a ServletContainerInitializer.

Use a Servlet Filter to force the setting.


If you are using embedded mode for Jetty, these are just a case of adding the listener or filter to the WebAppContext before you start it.
If you are using standalone mode you need to figure out how to get the filter or listener into the WebAppContext
This could be simply adding it via the ${jetty.base}/webapps/*.xml deployable XML files.
Or you will want these to be applied to all webapps being deployed by the Jetty DeploymentManager, which means these will need to exist in a jar that is only loaded into those environments (see Jetty module system and the [environment] section of the *.mod files to bind the module to a specific environment).  Then it's a matter of adding having a startup XML (also defined in the *.mod file) that adds a DeploymentManager lifecycle binding against the DEPLOYING stage that adds the filters or listener to the WebAppContext passing through that binding.
